# want to upload and insert 200 000 rows of data using excel file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to upload and insert (using mysql) 200 000 data using excel file in codeigniter but after 20 000 records it doesn't work.

Comment: Show your code, what are you trying?

Comment: pls read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask...

Answer (score 0):

You have to chunk your csv file to smaller once.

Another way to do it is also chunk but in your code (limit + offset) and send it to the queue and then run jobs in queue.